# selenium web driver does not return the value from cssSelector in java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have this jQuery selector as below.

jQuery("html body div input[name='customer_name']").val();

According to that I have created the selector for selenium as below.

By cusNameTxtField = By.cssSelector("html body div input[name='customer_name']");

First expression giving me the expected output in the browser console, but using the second expression it returns null value. Is there any issue with the second expression ?
And I am getting the String values as below in the java code.

String fieldText = waitForExpectedElement(cusNameTxtField, 10).getText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this is an `input` element you might want to try

```
waitForExpectedElement(cusNameTxtField, 10).getAttribute("value");
```